# Как правильно составить ТЗ?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-программирование

Бывают случаи, когда ТЗ предоставленное заказчиком неполное, плохо составленное или его вообще не существует. Какие тогда вопросы вы задаете прежде чем начать работу и чтобы потом не возникало вопросов у заказчика? Дизайн сайта бывает разной сложности и разного качества, но все же есть ли какие-то вопросы общего характера?

Comment: ГОСТ! http://www.rugost.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=108&Itemid=62

Comment: самые общие вопросы это цена и сроки:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В "сайте" есть две основные компоненты: функционал и дизайн.

1. По функционалу, даже "поведению" сайта все относительно просто: это описывается так же, как для любого другого программного обеспечения, разве что с поправкой на stateless-характер `HTTP`. Цели, средства, use cases и прочие варианты и методы описания "как это должно работать".
2. Что касается дизайна - то мои партнеры, занимающиеся дизайном, обычно поступают так: рисуют несколько набросков, из которых клиент потом выбирает понравившийся вариант. Далее этот набросок прорисовывается подробнее, после чего на этой картинке ставятся подписи обеих сторон, она получается статус "Приложение № (n+1): макет" и становится неотъемлемой частью общего ТЗ на сайт.

Что касается деталей реализации (например, табличная или блочная верстка будет использовать) - как мне кажется, их необязательно указывать в ТЗ кроме тех случаев, когда это а) критично б) заказчик имеет хорошее представление об этом.

Сам процесс написания ТЗ всегда трудоемок, требует вникания в предметную область Заказчика. Кстати, хорошо работает вопрос "а что Вам нравится из продукции конкурентов"? :)

Успехов!